# Why do buttons not want to change colors?

Tags: html, css, styles

### Hello everyone! I have a question about buttons on my website. Why don't the change colors?

My code

```css
#html .przyciski:nth-child(1) {
  color: white;
  background: #04AA6D;
}

#html .przyciski:nth-child(2) {
  color: black;
  background: #FFF4A3;
}

#html .przyciski:nth-child(3) {
  color: white;
  background: #282A35;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


  <div id="html">

    <span style="font-size: 5.3rem;">.HTML</span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 1rem;">Język do tworzenia stron internetowych</span><br><br>

    <button class="przyciski">Naucz się HTML</button><br>
    <button class="przyciski">Samouczek wideo</button><br>
    <button class="przyciski">Dokumentacja HTML</button><br>

  </div>


</div>
```

I'm just a beginner and I don't know what could be wrong. Please help.

Comment: Your `<button>` elements are actually the children 6, 7 and 8 of their `#html` parent. You have 2 sibling spans and 3 `<br>` before them. That's why your selectors don't work. 
In a near future the selector `:nth-child(an + b of S)` will be implemented on chrome

Comment: You could use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`, to target the element type instead of the position.

Answer (score -1):

The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child of its parent.

So, this means it's selecting the children, not the elements in order, for example, by using the `.przyciski:nth-child(1)` selector, you would be selecting the **first children inside the button.**

Your current CSS is selecting something like this:

```html
<button class="przyciski">
    <div></div> <== Your current CSS is selecting this element, which doesn't exist
</button>
```

A solution you can apply is by wrapping those buttons inside a div, something like this:

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

And select those buttons like this

```css
.buttons:nth-child(1) { /* <== Selecting the "Button 1" */
    color: #fdfdfd;
}

.buttons:nth-child(1) { /* <== Selecting the "Button 2" */
    color: #fcfcfc;
}

.buttons:nth-child(1) { /* <== Selecting the "Button 3" */
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

You can read more about `nth-child()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.php)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I already found the answer. There should be a reference to:

:nth-child(1)
:nth-child(3)
:nth-child(5).

This is because CSS3 also counts closing tags, that is </button>.